# Shopware plugin dependencies - additional PHP library

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6

I've created a plugin that requires an additional php library that is not in Shopware requirements. Because of that, I cannot install the plugin on Shopware test environment to push it through Shopware plugin store, because of unmet requirements.
The question is:

1. Is adding requirements for additional PHP libraries allowed? I cannot find anything in the guidelines.
2. How can I test this plugin in the test environment to push it to the store?

For more information: When i try to install plugin in test environment I am getting the below error

> Failed Dependency
>
> Required plugin/package "ext-imagick *" is missing or not installed and activated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem with missing PHP dependencies, just force your plug-in to the test phase, and when it gets rejected contact the tester that some additional libraries are required.

Also, you should add information about required libraries and who can install them to your plugin description/requirements so they are visible on the Shopware store page.

Answer (score 1):

Additional PHP dependencies can be installed over the composer.json since shopware 6.5, refer to the docs [here](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/using-composer-dependencies.html#adding-composer-dependencies).

So the only thing you have to do on plugin side is to set `executeComposerCommands` to true, that way your composer dependencies will be installed automatically when your plugin is installed.

```php
class SwagBasicExample extends Plugin
{
    public function executeComposerCommands(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

However, it is not possible over that way to add php extensions to the system (like the mentioned `ext-imagick`, as composer can't do that). That has to happen on the hosting side, as those are [platform packages](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#platform-packages).

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** instead of linking to external ressources

Comment: I'm aware that I can add additional vendor packages to my plugin. The whole problem is that this is a php extension that has to be handled by system/hosting. But my problem is that I want to push this plugin to the Shopware store. To do that plugin must go through some tests, but I cannot install it on the test environment provided by Shopware, because of lacks dependencies. 
Also, I wonder if this is not against the guidelines.

Comment: That's not possible in store plugins, as you can't make assumptions on the PHP environment of the shops that might install the plugin. What you can do instead is not requiring the extension, but checking at runtime if the methods are available and display an error if they are not.

Comment: That doesn't resolve the problem of putting the plugin in the store.